# How do I write output from within Python's LLVM bindings?

Tags: python, c, printf, llvm, llvm-py

I am using Python's [LLVM bindings](http://www.llvmpy.org/llvmpy-doc/0.11.2/doc) to generate code for a custom language.

Now I want to run programs and check if their output works correctly - but I am unable to figure out exactly *how* to output anything.

Is there some way to write to `stdout` or to a file using LLVM bindings?

Or do I need to call `printf` from the C library?

How do I do either one of these?

*Note: I am not using JIT / ExecutionEngine, so LLVM doesn't automatically find the `printf` function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM can generate an object file (`.o`) that should be able to link to `printf()` as long as you define it properly and link to `glibc` (or `msvcrt` if you're on Windows). They also seem to have a library called `llvm_cbuilder` as part of `llvmpy` that could help you do that. They even have a test case just for `printf()`:

https://github.com/llvmpy/llvmpy/blob/master/llvm_cbuilder/tests/test_print.py

Another option is to have your own suite of utility functions, including some that print. You can then pass a pointer to a table holding all of those to your generated function. What I like about this solution is that it allows you to load the generated function on runtime and avoid real linking (but you have to consider relocations).

Last but not least, [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) is always a good source of llvmpy examples.

Comment: Thanks for this - I believe the example in the `Github` url is exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm actually working on something similar. It would be nice if you can share the result on github or something.

Comment: I'll put something up when I actually get it to print. :D I'm just trying to write a module and link it in right now.